# How to migration of VM from public subnet to private subnet in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

How to migration of VM from public subnet to private subnet in Microsoft Azure?
Please help me how to solve this issue. I need to move my Virtual machine from Public to private.
I am a new guy in Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 4):

In Azure there’s no concept of public and private subnets, but it is possible to update subnet specific route tables manually and remove/update the Internet route. Alternatively, the same outcome can be achieved by not assigning a public IP address to a virtual machine.

This means that you don't actually need to migrate your VMs to another subnet, it's enough updated the route table of their current subnet.

Please take a look at this Azure tutorial for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal